# How to make the first option unselected while the component is rendered in select with multiple?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

First option is always being selected when the select multiple is loaded. It becomes un-selected only when it's selected by holding `ctrl` key or when other options are selected. The drawback of this feature is that the `onChange` event handler cannot be called when the first is the only option that's selected and submitted.

```
createSelectItems(input_items) {
    let items = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < input_items.length; i++) {
        items.push(<option key={i} value={input_items[i]}>{input_items[i]}</option>);
    }
    return items;

render() {
    if(this.state.interfaces.length>0){
    return (
        <div className="interfaces">
            <label>select interfaces for <strong>{this.props.device}</strong>
                <select onChange={this.onInterfaceSelected} multiple>
                    {this.createSelectItems(this.state.interfaces)}
                </select>
                <p>{this.state.selected_interfaces}</p>
            </label>
            { this.state.selected_interfaces.length >0 && <button className="submit" onClick={this.submitInterfaces}>submit</button>}
        </div>
    );
}
return null;
}
```

In this case; submit button doesn't show up as well. How can I mitigate this?

[image]

Comment: Did you mean to say as a placeholder?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale no, I mean to remove the grey background for `primary` when its loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your createSelectItems the following method,

```
createSelectItems(input_items) {
    let items = [];
    items.push(<option value={0} hidden>Select an option...</option>)
    for (let i = 0; i < input_items.length; i++) {
        items.push(<option key={i} value={input_items[i]}>{input_items[i]}</option>);
    }
    return items;
 }
```

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question, can you answer according to it?

Comment: `<option value={0} hidden={true}>Select an option...</option>` this works, thank you. I tried with `disabled` but it selects the next option by default which is again the first option `primary`. Can I edit your answer and accept?

Comment: I have edited, it's waiting for peer review, dunno who reviews

Comment: By default the first one is selected, so the onChange wont fire if you select first one.

Comment: @PrathisrihasReddy I have reviewd the edit, and accepted, can you accept the answer